# prepareForSegue: object

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.3, ios6

My app have core data and two views CoursesTableViewController and DetailViewController.

If the user tap on Detail Disclosure button segue to DetailViewController to show some details.

The app uses didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath for other things.

**CoursesTableViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];

    }

}
```

**DetailViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *courseCodeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *courseNameLabel;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;
@synthesize courseCodeLabel = _courseCodeLabel;
@synthesize courseNameLabel = _courseNameLabel;


#pragma mark - Managing the detail item



- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.courseCodeLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"courseCode"] description];
        self.courseNameLabel.text = [[self.detailItem valueForKey:@"courseName"] description];

    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    self.courseCodeLabel = nil;
    self.courseNameLabel = nil;

}
```

The problem is when I tap on Detail Disclosure the segue works good but in the DetailViewController there are no value in the courseCodeLabel and courseNameLabel.

Comment: Use the debugger and check the values of detailItem and your labels inside configureView. Either detailItem is nil, or your label outlets are not connected (and will be nil), or your key names are wrong.

Comment: When it reach the `setDetailItem` it  jumps over the (if statement) this mean `[self configureView]` will not work.

Comment: That suggests `detailItem` is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Import & try casting the destination view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

DetailViewController * detailVC = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

[detailVC setDetailItem:object];

}

}
```

Comment: With this you are passing the object correctly. Though I'm not sure if you can use auto synthesize with manual setter. I'd delete `@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;` and implement a getter as well.

Comment: I try but still the same problem!!